# Pending approval mail not sent

Tags: 7, users

<strike>Am using the [register module](http://drupal.org/project/register) to create an alternate registration page which requires admin approval. The pending approval mail is not sent to the user registering through the page.</strike>

Wish someone could help me here. I've also created an issue in the [module page](https://drupal.org/node/2152709). Thanks

The problem is not with the module. The pending approval mails are not sent even registering with default drupal path while rest of the mails are delivered.

Comment: Hello. How have you tested if it is not sent, and not merely never reaches it's destination?

Comment: Hey Molot, am working on identifying the issue. Nothing on log messages. Can you help me how to check if it's not being sent or delivered?

Comment: The way I do it will hardly help you - I bet you can't really intercept communication from your server? The beauty of virtual machines and cooperating admins is that you can easily test what comes out of the machine, but usually that's not the case. Try using [smtp](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) - it gives better control over your mails, and better logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check these variables:

```
user_mail_register_admin_created_notify
user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify
user_mail_register_pending_approval_notify
user_mail_status_blocked_notify
user_mail_cancel_confirm_notify
user_mail_status_canceled_notify
```

Use drush (`drush vget user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify`) or install [Mail Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailcontrol/); This module provide only interface modifications. The underlying functionality is already there by default in Drupal 7.

You can also drop in `settings.php`:

`$conf['user_mail_register_admin_created_notify'] = FALSE; 
$conf['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = FALSE; 
$conf['user_mail_register_pending_approval_notify'] = FALSE; 
$conf['user_mail_status_activated_notify'] = FALSE; 
$conf['user_mail_status_blocked_notify'] = FALSE; 
$conf['user_mail_cancel_confirm_notify'] = FALSE; 
$conf['user_mail_status_canceled_notify'] = FALSE;`